# jQuery AddClass then removing a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my Rails application, I send an Ajax request when the user hits the Save button, when it sends the request, I can return some jQuery.

What I'd like to do is add a class (saving), have a delay and then remove the class.

So, I added this:

```
$('.button').addClass('saving').delay(2000).removeClass('saving');
```

For some reason, it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) is actually for animations.

Use **[setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)**

```
$('.button').addClass('saving');

setTimeout(function () { 
    $('.button').removeClass('saving');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that `.delay()` was for animations. It's working, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

`delay` only works with animation-related methods, you can use `queue` method:

```
$('.button').addClass('saving').delay(2000).queue(function( next ){
    $(this).removeClass('saving'); 
    next();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rp6Xw/44/

Comment: @user1975031 Okay, fortunately `setTimeout` works for you. The possible reason is I had used `div` as selector in my code and you just copy/pasted it.

Comment: Nope, I changed the selectors to my spec

Comment: it is better to add next(); into callback function, so you can run it multiple times. like so:
$(".button").addClass("saving").delay(1000).queue(function(next){
    $(this).removeClass("saving");
    next();
});

Answer (score 4):

If someone needs more than one adding/removing of the class,  .dequeue(); is also requered to function properly.

```
$('.button').addClass('saving').delay(2000).queue(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('saving'); 
   $(this).dequeue();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe:

```
$('.button').addClass('saving').delay(2000, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('saving')
});
```

Comment: Close! You need to have `.delay(2000).queue(function () { });` as in @undefined's answer and it'll work

Answer (score 1):

Shortest way.

```
$(".button").addClass("saving").show(0).delay(2000).removeClass("saving");
```